# Remesh modifier script won't let me modify scale

Tags: scripting, modifiers, add-on, source-code, remesh

So I made a script with two independent properties for the octree depth and scale features in the remesh modifier. The octree depth one works fine, but the scale one has no effect. what am I doing wrong? Pictures attached.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Property voxelgenScale is outside the permitted range for scale.

```
The ratio of the largest dimension of the model over the size of the grid
Type: float in [0, 0.99], default 0.9
```

[Remesh Modifier](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.RemeshModifier.html?highlight=remesh%20modifier#bpy.types.RemeshModifier.scale)

```
voxelgenScale : bpy.props.FloatProperty(
                                        name = 'Scale',
                                        default = 0.9,
                                        min = 0,
                                        max = 0.99,
                                        description = 'something',
                                        )
```

Comment: Ok, that definitely helps. However, now when i run the script, the scale parameter has disappeared completely. I haven't touched anything but the number values, my script now looks like this \/

 voxelgenScale: bpy.props.IntProperty(
    name = "Scale",
    default = 0.9,
    min = 0,
    max = 0.99,

Comment: I propose to use a float property for input (Type: float). Integer properties with float numbers in default, min, max raises TypeError: integer argument expected, got float